# Why does my tableau tooltip get changed when I change my data source?

Tags: tableau-api

I am moving from a csv to a postgresSQl for my tableau workbook. Both of them have the same field names, exact data types. However, when I change my data source the tooltip gets a random text which breaks the filter in the toolip viz

I tried replacing the csv file with the same csv file and the same thing happened. So I think this is a tableau issue and not a database issue

```
<Sheet name="Tooltip:  Level 2 Site Scores" maxwidth="300" maxheight="300" filter="<Site>,<[federated.02mez2l0u2i0o018sk45f0skmrv7].[none:level_2:nk]>"> (This is what happens)

<Sheet name="Tooltip:  Level 2 Site Scores" maxwidth="300" maxheight="300" filter="<Level 2>,<Site>"> (This is what I want)
```

The 'Level 2' field gets messed up for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you open Tableau desktop file in a text editor, you'll see that it's an XML. In an example, I have a file with the following line. Tableau assigns a unique id to calculated fields I create, this is the "Calculation_104990228446113793"

```
<column-instance column='[Calculation_104990228446113793]' derivation='None' name='[none:Calculation_104990228446113793:nk]' pivot='key' type='nominal' />
```

The same can be seen for data source references.

```
 <datasource caption='my_data_source' inline='true' name='federated.0dbu8r50hqicaj1fm4f2b1r4o814' version='10.5'>
```

So when you swap a data source, unique id's change and cause the error you're seeing. Not sure if your issue is a bug or not, you could report it. But this is what is happening in your case.